# Extract matching string from start

Tags: python, regex, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x

Using Python 2.7

Lets say I have a pattern string `abb` and a search string `abab`.
I want to get the sliced part of the pattern string that matches as much as  possible with the search string from the beginning, i.e., I want the expression to return just `ab` because only that much of the pattern string is at the beginning of the search string. I have been through the [google page on regex](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) and the regex [howto page](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto) as well but couldn't find a way. Just a hint would be enough.

I have written the following code which gives the right answer, but I'm looking for something more efficient.

```
pat_str='abb'
search_str='abab'
pat_length=len(pat_str)
for each in xrange(pat_length,0,-1):
    if re.search('^'+pat_str[:each],search_str):
        return_str=pat_str[:each]
        break

print return_str
```

**Edit:**
Corresponding elements should be same. Break at the first instance where the corresponding elements aren't same and return the preceding string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a regular expression (not in a way that makes sense), but you don't need to; it's simple to implement in a function that works for any number of strings:

```
def longest_match(*strings):
    match = []
    for tup in zip(*strings):
        if len(set(tup)) == 1:
            match.append(tup[0])
        else:
            break

    return ''.join(match)

print(longest_match('abc123', 'abc456'))  # abc
print(longest_match('abc123', 'abc456', 'abyz'))  # ab
print(longest_match('ababc', 'csrabab'))  # <prints empty line>
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, how so? It's working for me, unless somehow the output is wrong and I'm not seeing it (which doesn't seem likely). The comments currently in the answer are the output for those lines.

Comment: `p  = "ababc"``s = "csrabab"`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, that should print nothing, because not even the first character matches. That's what my code does.

Comment: There is a `c` in `p`, *ab because only that much of the pattern string is at the beginning of the search string.*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I think you've misunderstood the question. What output do you think your example should give?

Comment: The OP wants to find the largest chunk from the substring/pattern that is at the start of the string itself so it should return `c`,  `abab` is a bad example, `adab` would have been more informative

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm afraid you did misunderstand. The text in the question _could_ be clearer, but the OP's code does what mine does, and the OP said, "I have written the following code _which gives the right answer_, ..."

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agreed, I should have put in more details and a better example to avoid the misunderstanding. Will update the post

Comment: The OP's code does not do what the description of the question asks, it is worded as the maximal prefix based of slices from the pattern string.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it does; the text is just not as clear/precise as it could be, certainly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I'm not trying to 'beat you' here, or rub in that you misunderstood; I quite possibly misunderstood that question earlier about not showing the password, so it's not like I'm talking from a high horse or anything :).

Comment: @Cyphase, don't worry, I don't take the internet too seriously ;)   The line *I want to get the sliced part of the pattern string that matches as much as possible with the search string from the beginning* does leave a lot of ambiguity, you can slice a string anywhere

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, sure, I agree. But since Clock Slave said the code worked, I took that as the final spec.

Comment: [Code is much more precise than words](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#handling-docstring-indentation).

Answer (score 1):

Considering you only want to find a match at the start, just zip, compare and return.

```
from itertools import izip

def sub_match(s, sub):
    out = ""
    for a, b in izip(s, sub): # zip python3
        if a != b:
            return out
        out += a
    return out
```

If you want to find any matches in sub:

```
from itertools import islice,  izip
def sub_match(s, sub):
    all_m = []
    for i in range(len(sub)):
        out = ""
        for a, b in izip(s, islice(sub,i,None)):
            if a != b:
                all_m.append(out)
                break
            out += a
        else:
            all_m.append(out)
    return max(all_m, key=len)
```

Output:

```
In [12]: s = "csrababc"

In [13]: p =  "ababc"

In [14]: sub_match(s,p)
Out[14]: 'c'

In [15]: s = "ababdc"

In [16]: sub_match(s,p)
Out[16]: 'abab'
```

Comment: @ClockSlave so you are saying the first solution is what you want?

Comment: @ClockSlave, ok cool, if you are using python2 use `itertools.izip` instead of z

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression that you are describing is

```
(a(b(a(b?)?)?)?
```

You may construct it dynamically from your pattern:

```
import re
pattern = 'abab'
search_str = 'abb'

# Construct the regexp that I mentioned above
regexp = ''
for c in reversed(pattern):
    regexp = '(%s%s)?' % (re.escape(c), regexp)

m = re.match(regexp, search_str)
print 'Result is %r' % m.group(0)
```

This is assuming you really want to use regular expressions.  The other answers have good solutions without re.

Also try googling for "longest common string prefix".

**Update:** The regexp was wrong (kind of reversed), fixed it.

Comment: Indeed, but don't forget to anchor the pattern at the start of the string.

Comment: Casimir, `re.match` will always anchor at the start. That's how it differs from `re.search`.

Comment: I was not speaking about the `^` anchor, but about the first character "a" that must not be optional. (otherwise the match will be always true)

Comment: Yes, it will always be true, but it will return an empty string as the match. That's what the other solutions here will do, too. (OP will get an error in that case because he did not define the string variable before the loop.) On the other hand, I just fixed an unrelated problem in my regexp, see also the update.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
import itertools

pattern = "ab"
search_string = "abab"

print "".join([x for x,y in itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p[0] == p[1], itertools.izip(pattern, search_string))])
```

Comment: You don't need to construct a list here, `"".join(x for x, y in ...)` will also work.

Comment: @Suor, it is less efficient to use a generator

Comment: Was just doing a quick timing test to confirm how big the difference was.

Comment: A generator is always going to be slower, python builds a list internally if you pass a generator so one way or another there is going to be a list